# Deferred Array $.when.apply(...) Runs too soon

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, promise, deferred

The following $.when.apply(...) runs instantly, rather than awaiting the completion of posting each file provided in the deferred array.  I have tried numerous approaches, the code works fine, but the deferred array behaves as though it is instantly completed, rather than waiting for the completion of all ajax calls first.

```
function handleFiles() {
  showUploadingSpinnerOnModal() 

  var metadata = []
  var rootFolderSelected = $("#root-folder").val()
  var childFolderSelected = $("#child-folder").val()
  metadata["rootFolderName"] = rootFolderSelected
  metadata["childFolderName"] = childFolderSelected

  $.when.apply($, loopThroughFiles(metadata)).then(function(deferredArry) {
      // do something after
      console.log("2: ", deferredArry)
      updateViews()
  })
} 

function loopThroughFiles(metadata) {
  deferredArry = []
  $.each(containerFiles, function(index, file) {
      deferredArray.push(postNewFile(file, metadata))
      console.log("added promise to deferred array");
  })
  return deferredArry
}
```

// Post New File...

```
function postNewFile(fileObj, metadata) {

    var getFile = getFileBuffer()

    getFile.done(function(arrayBuffer) {
        var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer, fileObj)
        addFile.done(function(file, status) {
            var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri)
            getItem.done(function(listItem, status) {
                var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata, metadata)
                changeItem.done(function(data, status) {
                    console.log("File Uploaded and Metadate Updated")
                })
                changeItem.fail(onError)
            })
            getItem.fail(onError)
        })
        addFile.fail(onError)
    })
    getFile.fail(onError)


    function getFileBuffer() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred()
        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result)
        }
        reader.onerror = function(e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error)
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileObj)
        return deferred.promise()
    }


    function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer, fileObj) {
        var apiUrl = PROJECT_BASE_URL + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('documentLibrary')/Files/add(url='" + fileObj.name + "',overwrite=true)"
        return $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl,
            method: 'POST',
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "contentType": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "content-Length": arrayBuffer.byteLength,
                "X-RequestDigest": formDigest
            }
        })
    }

    function getListItem(fileURI) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: fileURI,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            }
        })
    }

    function updateListItem(fileMetadata) {
        var data = {
            __metadata: {
                'type': 'SP.Data.DocumentlibraryItem'
            }
        }
        data['RootFolder'] = metadata.rootFolderName
        data['ChildFolder'] = metadata.childFolderName

        return $.ajax({
            url: fileMetadata.uri,
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            async: true,
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-length": data.length,
                "IF-MATCH": fileMetadata.etag,
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "X-RequestDigest": formDigest
            }
        })
    }
}

function onError(error) {
    console.log(error.responseText)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`postNewFile()` does not return a promise.  In fact, it doesn't return anything so when you're pushing items into the array, you're just creating an array of `undefined` values.  Therefore, you're passing an array of `undefined` values to `$.when()` and since that array contains no promises, it has nothing to wait for.

You need to properly return a promise from `postNewFile()` that will be resolved or rejected only when all the asynchronous operations in that file are done.  All those asynchronous operations should also be properly chained together so they are sequenced and so their promises are linked (for both completion and error).